# Scroll Event Listener: Empty While loop, how does it work and why?

Tags: javascript

This question is in reference to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52025615/vanilla-js-change-active-state-of-links-when-scrolling-refactoring).

In summary, the requirement is to have the links in the navigation to change status based on the current scroll position, I was able to get the code presented here to work, but one line which I don't understand why it's done this way is

```
while(--index && window.scrollY + 50 < sections[index].offsetTop) {}
```

I would've commented on the original answer post, but apparently, my reputation is not enough yet.

This is the whole JavaScript code

```js
const links = document.querySelectorAll('.links');
const sections = document.querySelectorAll('section');

function changeLinkState() {
  let index = sections.length;

  while(--index && window.scrollY + 50 < sections[index].offsetTop) {}
  
  links.forEach((link) => link.classList.remove('active'));
  links[index].classList.add('active');
}

changeLinkState();
window.addEventListener('scroll', changeLinkState);
```

Why is the while loop needed and since it's empty wouldn't it do anything?
I tried removing the while loop and it ended up breaking the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while(--index && window.scrollY + 50 < sections[index].offsetTop) {}
```

This decrements the index with each iteration. The loop stops when `window.scrollY + 50 < sections[index].offsetTop` is false, and the index remains to the value of the last 'passed' check.

It is later used to update `links[index].classList.add('active');`

It could have been written like this also:

```
while (index >= 0 && window.scrollY + 50 < sections[index].offsetTop) {
    index--
}
```

It is required to check if index has a adequate value (aka not -1 or lower), or it will error when it reached -1, as `sections[-1].something` does not exist.